# Using multiple contexts in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm a relative newbie with regards to React JS, I am trying to get my use of contexts working.

I have an app, when the entry component (App) is defined with

```
    <Router>
        <div className="app">
            <GlobalContextProvider>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/CodeSystem" component={PageCodeSystem} />
                    <Route path="/ValueSet" component={PageValueSet} />
                    <Route path="/RefSets" component={PageRefSets} />
                    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                </Switch>
            </GlobalContextProvider>
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Further down the component tree I have a composed that uses its own context shared with its children components.

```
        <QueryVSContextProvider>
            <ValueSetSidebar />
            <ValueSetBody />
        </QueryVSContextProvider>
```

From the above, within the ValueSetBody component I have:

```
class ValueSetBody extends Component {
    static contextType = QueryVSContext;

    render() {
        const { bundle } = this.context;

        ...

        }
}
```

How could I also access the "GlobalContext" which was defined up at the App component?
I want to be able to detect changes in the GlobalContext from the class component.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is using `<Context.Consumer>`. For example:

```
class ValueSetBody extends Component {

    ...

    render() {
        <QueryVSContext.Consumer>
            {queryVSContext =>
                (<GlobalContext.Consumer>
                    {globalContext =>
                        (<div>
                            {queryVSContext.value}
                            {globalContext.value}
                            ...
                        </div>)
                    }
                </GlobalContext.Consumer>)
            }
        </QueryVSContext.Consumer>
    }
}
```

If you're going to use context in many places then maybe it would be better to create HOC or use render-prop technique. Example of HOC:

```
function connectGlobalContext(Component) {
    return function (props) {
        return <GlobalContext.Consumer>
            {context =>
                <Component {...props} globalContext={context}/>
            }
        </GlobalContext.Consumer>
    }
}
```

After you've created HOC you can wrap your components that need the context:

```
class ValueSetBody extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (<div>
            {this.props.globalContext.value}
        </div>)
    }
}

export default connectGlobalContext(ValueSetBody);
```

Now you can create HOC for `QueryVSContext` the same way and use both contexts anywhere you need them.

Comment: Thanks @KenBekov - That's more complex than I have covered so far. I'll try and modify my code accordingly. I'll try the first method first, and then work out how I access the properties outside of the JSX.

Comment: Well, the first method works - I'll try out the second shortly.